# Does Work Manager Wake The Application Class? Does It Run On Application Process or Another Process?

Tags: android, background-process, android-workmanager

Android documentation does not clearly tells about what and how a work manager runs a work.

**1.** Does `Work Manager` start the `application` class so that initialization for some classes can be done or i have to manually initialize them in my Worker class.

**2.** Does It run on `application process` or it runs on another `process`?

**3.** Periodic work is not running if my application is killed. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It store the jobs in a **local database** and tells the `OS` to run them using `JobScheduler` or `gcmNetworkManger` or `AlarmManger` depending on the API.
2. The `OS` wakes the app when the **constraints** are met to run the `scheduled job`.
3. **Yes!** if the user choice to **force stop** the app, the `OS` **deletes** all the scheduled job and the `WorkManger` won't be able to reschedule them until you open the app.